# Login com facebook Android

Tags: android

Estou estudando ainda programação pra apps, estou com uma dúvida que pra vocês deve ser simples, criei um app e uma aplicação Rest o usuário faz o cadastro no app e salvo os dados em um banco de dados MySQL, quando o usuário loga eu salva os dados dele localmente utilizando sqlite pra quando ele fechar o app e abrir novamente verifico se ele já está logado ou não, até ai tudo bem... 
agora to implementando um botão de login com Facebook, e estou perdido, eu até consegui fazer toda implementação e esta funcionando, minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Ao logar pelo Facebook devo salvar esses dados também no MySQL, ou deixo o Facebook gerenciar isso?
Nos usuários cadastrados eles podem alterar seus dados no app como e-mail e senha e quando é via Facebook como fica?

Comment: Já existem várias [perguntas com resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5Dlogin+do+Facebook) sobre o assunto, verifique se alguma lhe atende.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso quem decide é o engenheiro de software ou programador. O dono da aplicação. A única coisa que você precisa fazer é pedir a autorização do  usuário, por meio de login e senha, para acessar os dados dele. O que fazer co os dados depende de sua arquitetura e do modelo seguido pela aplicação.

Isso, efetivamente, é uma questão de onde você quer chegar e como você quer chegar com sua *app*.

Não acho que você deveria armazenar as informações que estão no Facebook, mas para responder definitivamente, você deveria se perguntar qual a criticidade e sensibilidade dos dados requeridos pela sua aplicação.

Veja o caso do Spotify: o cadastro com os dados do Facebook está completamente derivado da sua conta na rede social em questão. Se você encerrar sua conta do Facebook, você é desconectado do Spotify.

**Veja** [***Facebook for developers***](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/overview)